# remove hard coded values from view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, tblSwaps. It looks a bit like below.

```
swapdate    region     bb_ticker     swap_units
2017-01-01  EU         ABC           10
2017-01-01  US         ABC           40
2017-01-01  EU         DEF           13
2017-01-01  US         DEF           12
2017-02-20  EU         ABC           8
2017-02-20  US         ABC           40
2017-02-20  EU         DEF           13
2017-02-20  US         DEF           12
```

I also have another table, tblCodes

```
code
ABC
DEF
```

I then have a view, vw_SwapTotal, query below. This basically sums the number of swap units for each bb_ticker for a certain date.

```
SELECT        swapdate, bb_ticker, SUM(swap_units) AS total_swap_units
FROM          tblSwaps
GROUP BY swapdate, bb_ticker
```

I have created another view (this is where I have a question) shown below, which makes use of the view above (not sure if this is the best idea or not). The problem which the query below is that I have hard coded the bb_tickers (ABC, DEF) in which is not ideal as in the future there will be new bb_tickers.

```
  SELECT        *
  FROM          vw_SwapTotal
  WHERE         bb_ticker IN ('ABC', 'DEF'))
  SELECT        swapdate, isnull(ABC, 0) ABC, isnull(DEF, 0) DEF
  FROM          swp AS source PIVOT (max(total_swap_units) FOR bb_ticker IN ([ABC], [DEF])) AS pvt
```

What is the best way to get rid of the hard coded bb_tickers in this view?

Comment: What is the condition how to choose the `bb_ticker` values? In your example it was enough to use `IN(SELECT DISTINCT bb_ticker FROM tblSwaps)` but this doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you want?

```
WHERE         bb_ticker IN (select distinct bb_ticker from tblSwaps))
```

Comment: yes that would work for the where condition part. However how would I do the select part, ie. isnull(ABC,0) ABC, isnull(DEF,0) DEF